# Strikethrough text in Adobe Flex 4

Tags: text, flex4, strikethrough

How to make strikethrough text in Adobe Flex 4?
I mean using native flex framework features: styles, libraries, classes.
I use `RichText` component.

Please, do not answer:

- draw line
- make it underlined and change baseline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lineThrough, as in:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS4C9DCBEF-6671-47e9-BBC1-F2676529A30A.html

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Text Layout Framework](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/textlayout/demos/) can do so.

[Usage](http://www.learnosity.com/techblog/index.cfm/2008/12/16/Flash-Text-Layout-Framework--Getting-Started)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Graphic xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/fxg/2008" version="2">    
    <RichText>
       <content>This text is <span fontWeight="bold">BOLD</span>,<br/> 
       this text is <span textDecoration="underline">UNDERLINED</span>,<br/>
       and this text is <span fontStyle="italic">ITALIC</span>.
       <p>This is a new paragraph.</p></content>
    </RichText>
</Graphic>
```